# MacOS/Safari JavaScript Async/Await Failures

Tags: macos, outlook, safari, office-js

Trying to see if this is only me, but users of my add-in in Mac Outlook are all of a sudden reporting that a dialog I load using the displayDialogAsync is turning up blank.

So, I rebuilt the page being called so that I can call it in Safari without the Office API.
The page loads and functions perfectly in Chrome, Edge and FireFox.But in Safari it fails. It specifically fails where/when I make a call to an aync function, and a parameter I pass (no matter the type), is always undefined. So, I know it is not the office-js library, because it ONLY happens in Safari.

So, I opened my mailbox in Safari (outlook.office365.com) to see if I could glean more info for why the dialog fails to load, maybe get the console info. When I then clicked my add-in from Outlook online, the taskpane opened and bombed right off the bat on a line: Office.context.mailbox.item.getBodyAsync(). I see Office initialized, but I then work at collecting the details of the mail item in an async function and I see any call I make in an async way bombs - but only in Safari. All this same code works EXACTLY as expected in Chrome, Edge and FireFox.

Odder still, is if I put a COPY of all my variables in the GLOBAL space and when I see the parameter in the async/await function is undefined and I assign it to the global copy, viola - it all works in Safari.

Here is the code that calls my async function:

```
window.addEventListener("onload", async () => {
      // stuff here...
      // then...
      Office.onReady(async () => {
        const parentData = JSON.parse(window.atob(decodeURIComponent(o_q_s_data)));
        // NOTE: console.log() here to output parentData is a valid
        //       object and parentData.data is a stringified JSON 
        //       object, and again all this works in Chrome, FF, and 
        //       Edge, but not Safari
        await buildForm(null, parentData);
      });
});
```

And here is the code that fails:

```
buildForm = async (t, parentData) => {
  // in Safari and only Safari, when I get here 
  // parentData is "undefined"
  const data = JSON.parse(parentData.data); 
...
};
```

Worse is that this was all working 100% in Mac Outlook when I ran through my full test past a month or two ago. And it worked before it was inserted into the store as it was tested by Microsoft. So, I am at a loss.

So, is anyone else having problems of late in Mac Safari/Web kit/Mac Outlook?
Any ideas?

-- FOLLOW ON --

As I dig in deeper I am finding all sorts of bad stuff on Mac Safari based JavaScript code. I have a function that encrypts a user PIN for example via AES-CBC. The value generated by Safari JavaScript is incompatible with the same code via Chrome, Edge, FireFox on the same computer. It is incompatible with my backend PHP.

And I have found two more places where values I pass to an await function are undefined. I grab the PIN and the KEY from two input boxes on the HTML page. I then call an await function(KEY, PIN) and every time, KEY is "undefined." I swapped the values function(PIN,KEY), and then PIN was undefined.

At this point I would say it is my machine and memory corruption but my users are reporting an error to me which I traced to the fact that the first value in these async/await functions are "undefined."

Since there is does not appear to be an uproar over a problem like this, it must be my code. I am doing something that is fine in every browser but Safari it appears. :( I am working to simplify the code...

-- UPDATE --

So, I build the page on the fly all DHTML via ES6. I make several async calls to call the backend and update the page components async, so the page is loaded and you see things filling in. Once all the parts are there, the buttons enable, the user clicks the button and then they get a form. They supply information into two inputboxes and then press a submit button. The submit button collects the values, creates an instance of my backend wrapper and calls a function on the object async. This is where it failed. The values going into the async function.

FIX: added all values to the constructor or a non-async getter/setter BEFORE I make the async function call. Once all values set, I then call the async/await function parameterless. Works everywhere now.

Ugly, but that is what it takes.

Answer (score 0):

So, I build the page on the fly all DHTML via ES6. I make several async calls to call the backend and update the page components async, so the page is loaded and you see things filling in. Once all the parts are there, the buttons enable, the user clicks the button and then they get a form. They supply information into two inputboxes and then press a submit button. The submit button collects the values, creates an instance of my backend wrapper and calls a function on the object async. This is where it failed. The values going into the async function.

FIX: added all values to the constructor or a non-async getter/setter BEFORE I make the async function call. Once all values set, I then call the async/await function parameterless. Works everywhere now.

```
class MyObject {
    #p1 = null;
    #p2 = null;
    constrcutor(p1, p2) {
        this.#p1 = p1;
        this.#p2 = p2;
    }
    goGet = async () => {
        console.log(this.#p1);
        console.log(this.#p2);
        return "Hello World";
    };
}
function onLoad() {
    window.setTimeout( async() => {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = `<button id="myButton">click me...</button>`;
        const button = document.getElementById("myButton");
        button.addEventListener("click", async ()=> {
            const param1 = "Foo";
            const param2 = "Bar";
            console.log(param1);
            console.log(param2);
            const myObj = new MyObject();
            const result = await myObj.goGet(param1, param2);
        });
    }, 1);
}
```

Ugly, but that is what it takes.